# Can I removes a collection of aggregate roots in a single transaction?

Tags: domain-driven-design

When I was reading the chapter about Aggregates in *Implementing Domain-Driven Design*, I learnt that generally I should not change multiple aggregate instances in one transaction.

Later in the chapter about implementing Repository, I found a **removeAll** method is defined in the Repository interface then I get confused: isn't invoking **removeAll**, in other words, removing multiple aggregates from repository, violating the rule that change only one aggregate instance in one transaction?

Comment: You would have to ask Vaughn about that ;) Personnaly I don't even see a use for `remove`. http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/

Comment: Actually logically removing aggregate instance (marking it as unusable, disabled, or whatever) is mentioned in the book, but no matter how `removeAll` is implemented, if other users alter one of the instances which I am batch removing, transaction failure emerges. That's why I get puzzled.

Comment: Does the concurrency conflict really matter? Perhaps in the case of a removal the exception can be ignored. At that point it shouldn't matter what other business process was performed on the AR since you are deleting it entirely.

Comment: In the real scenario of mine, it does not matter because it is unlikely to happen. So I think maybe batch removal is also a special case that can break the rule (in case it is appropriate to offer such a batch operation)?

Comment: Yes, it could be a valid reason to break the rule. However, you could also implement the whole operation where every removal happens in it's own transaction. In theory, a removal operation failure shouldn't affect the result of another removal operation.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends.**

Personally, I'd consider it a design smell if a **user deletes multiple aggregates** in one go, exactly for the reason you state.

On the other hand, I often see **background jobs that do clean up** stuff. It is not uncommon to have a `removeAll` functionality in the sense you ask about in such code.

The reason why the "Modify only one aggregate per transaction" rule exists is simple: Aggregates are a concept that *define* consistency boundaries, so every time you break the one aggregate rule, you work against your own design. This is why you should have a good reason to break the rule, otherwise don't do it.